# How do I prevent page caching on a Classic ASP app?

Tags: asp-classic, cache-control

I need some pages **not** to be cached on a Classic ASP app, but I've tried every possible combination of headers and nothing seems to work:

```
Response.Expires         = -1
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1
Response.CacheControl    = "no-cache; private; no-store; must-revalidate; max-stale=0; post-check=0; pre-check=0; max-age=0"
Response.AddHeader         "Cache-Control", "no-cache; private; no-store; must-revalidate; max-stale=0; post-check=0; pre-check=0; max-age=0"  ' Same as previous line, I know, just in case.
Response.AddHeader         "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader         "Expires", "-1"
```

I've also tried restarting both the website and IIS, to no avail. When I leave the page and return to it using the browser's back button, it doesn't reload.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**: After a lot of more googling, I have found and implemented [this JavaScript solution](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript), it's not bullet-proof since it's client-side, and I would prefer a Server-Side solution, but it does the job!

**Still, I would like to hear about any server-side options.**

Answer (score 9):

You are operating under the impression that the result of the browser's back button is related to HTTP caching, it is not.

The provision of the back button is at the discretion of the browser which is from a HTTP stack point of view the *application*.  An application has no obligation to consider the caching requirements of any http request(s) that was used to render the contents of a window.  Indeed many browsers are capable of displaying content delivered through other protocols than http.

Consider the most common scenario for using the back button.  A user gets some search results from a web search engine (google, bing, ...), clicks on one of the results, quickly sees that the content is not what they were looking for and clicks the back button.  In order to optomise the user's experience most browsers will hold on to many of the resources (even the window into which the page is rendered) of a page when navigation from the page occurs.   The back button can then be implemented by reassembling those resources or even simply making the original window visible again.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Anthony, very clarifying, +1. So how do I achieve reloading the page after the Back button is pressed?

Comment: Nice explanation +1  and 100K :)

Answer (score 5):

Seem right.. try using this.

Run these statement **before** sending any HTML to the user, that is before any `Response.Write` or `<%=foo()%>`

```
Response.Buffer = True
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
```

Corrected the misspelled word Response.

Comment: Your last three lines was exactly how I started, then after no results I started adding to the code until it became those 6 lines I posted. I have `Response.Buffer = True` on the page as well, and no, I haven't sent anything to the browser before those 6 lines. I still tried your code (again) but nothing. At this point I'm almost certain that this problem doesn't have anything to do with the code, but with what?

Comment: have you tried IISRESET and clearing the cache after you have added these lines ? you might also want to check the settings in your IIS for caching what iis version do you use ?

Comment: IIS 7.5. I tried IISRESET (which I assume also clears the cache?). Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When you press the back button some browser always cach. There is a way to catch the event back button of the explorer and do something though could be gruesome. You can load the data of the page via AJAX and preventing caching with a randon variable generated via javascript.
Let me know if you need an example please...

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the particular page caching on a Classic ASP. Please try below code:

```
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" %>
```

Add above code under  section.